# Spring Rest docs - i18n support

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest, spring-restdocs

im currently thinking how to build REST API docs for my application with support for multiple languages. Endpoints, parameter names and return values should stay the same but the description of each REST method i want to provide in different supported languages.

Im using Spring boot, data & rest and found this docs project what seems very useful to me. Anyway, i couldn't find any informations in the docs regards the i18n topic/support.

Does anybody know if Spring REST docs support the generation of the API doc for multiple languages (in general)?

Answer (score 3):

REST Docs doesn't provide any out-of-the-box support for I18N but it should be pretty straightforward to build something on top.

The main piece with which REST Docs is involved and that I think you'd want to translate are the descriptions that are included in the various snippets. Rather than hard-coding a particular description, you could look each up in a `ResourceBundle`:

```
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("field-descriptions");

mockMvc.perform(get("/").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andDo(document("example", responseFields(
        fieldWithPath("a").description(resourceBundle.getString("a")),
        fieldWithPath("a.b").description(resourceBundle.getString("a.b")))));
```